# How to override permissions in a Registry Key using WiX?

Tags: permissions, wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX Installer which writes to the Windows Registry:
`HKLM\Software\Foo`

`Foo` and its descendants should be only editable by Administrators (Users will only be able to read)

The real case is that `Foo` (in previous releases) have been written with editable permission for Users (!!).

Considering this situation, how would you explicitly remove Users writable permission in Foo (and its descendant)?

I've tried `PermissionEx` (from util wix extension) with no good results at all (permission are not changed). Code:

```
<Component Id="ComponentId" Guid="[GENERATE-GUID]]">
    <RegistryKey Id="reg857CD83358A344C2982DC6BA6B047754" Root='HKLM' Key='SOFTWARE\Foo' Action='createAndRemoveOnUninstall'>
      <util:PermissionEx User="Users" GenericRead="yes" Read="yes" GenericWrite="no"/>
      <RegistryValue Id="regFD4780BBE853437A9D778D0B51D2E6AD" Type='string' Key='Bar' Name='prop_name' Value='prop_value' KeyPath="yes"/>
    </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer and accept it when you are satisfied that it is the best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [WiX Permission Builtin](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_permission.htm) instead of [util:PermissionEx extension](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_permissionex.htm) seems to do the trick. However you'll have to set permission in each object.

The next post was helpful to me: [Wix RegistryKey Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980452/wix-registrykey-permission)